# Best practices of making object converter

Tags: java, oop

I've faced a problem that can not solve by myself, thus, I'm asking for your help. The problem is following:
We have to upgrade persistence layer. Previously project used JDBC to access data, but now it should use JPA. It means that now data is retrieved in new objects, but system works with old ones. Thus, we should write some converters between old and new entities. But the problem is that sometimes to form new entity from old one we need some additional info. For example:

```
class OldEntity{
    private int id;
    // old entity contains only foreign key
    private int otherEntityId;
    ...
}

class NewEntity{
    private int id;
    // new entity contains object that associated with foreign key
    private OtherEntity otherEntity;
    ...
}
```

We want to add some general interface to all converters, but if we convert from old entity to new one, firstly, we should retrieve "otherEntity" by its id and give it to the converter. As we have a lot of entities with different structures, converter's method should recieve various number of different parameters to form new entity.
The question is: is there any good architecture solution for such problem?

Comment: How are you going to get the additional info?  Pop up a dialog box to the user?

Comment: No. It will be retrieved from database by foreign key value. Like in the classes from example: we have only foreign key value in the old entity and want to fill the whole object retrieved by it's id in the new one. I think it's bad idea to retrieve it inside converter methods, so, I'm looking for the better way to give such retrieved objects to appropriate converter's method.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to configure mapping so that it produce old entities and no converter needed?

Comment: Of cause it is, but old entities have very poor contents, as an example, they store foreign key values instead of appropriate objects, thus, it's very awkward to work with them. We need new entities for further development, but we don't want to refactor legacy components that support old entities only.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a job for the [Adapter Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered-0). Your application expects OldEntities but persistance is now managed by NewEntities, so there's a need of an adapter that manages the conversion between OldEntities and NewEntities.

Then, you will need to build an Adapter for every entity in your Domain Model. They should look like this:

```
class NewEntityAdapter extends OldEntity{
    private NewEntity newEntity; 

    //This is an overriden method
    public int getOtherEntityId(){
        return newEntity.getOtherEntity().getId();

}
```

Comment: Yes. It's good solution, but the problem arosed when I try to convert in other direction. It's easy to get old entity from new one as it stores less amount of information inside. But if I want to form new entity from old I need to retrieve additional information somewere and give it to the method that makes converting. I think it's not a good idea to retrieve it inside adapter.

Comment: Do you use a Service Layer? The Service Layer would be a nice place to ask the DAO Layer to get a NewEntity instance based on the ID information that Old Entities contains. Because of its transaction support I think is the best place where you can do such operations.

Comment: Sure. All conversations should be done on service layer and I can retreive all requirement data there. But I think it looks kind of messy because different entities has different number of such additional parameters that should be given to the adapter's constructor or converter method. I don't like the approach with adapters, because it spawns a lot of additional classes. My idea was to create converters that have some general interface. The problem here is how to give that parameters to the convertor's method. One of the bad, but useful approaches is to use Map for additional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
public interface IBaseEntity{

    public int getId();

}

public class OldEntity implements IBaseEntity{
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
}

public class NewEntity{
    IBaseEntity entity;
    public NewEntity(IBaseEntity entity){
        this.entity=entity;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return entity.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's viable solution. But I really need converters, to move conversion logic outside the entity classes.